# DocuSign REST API ColdFusion: No Unique Envelope IDs

Tags: rest, coldfusion, unique, docusignapi, envelope

I have ColdFusion code which closely follows this and works fine--for the most part:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/Basic%20Scenarios/Creating%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm

What I am trying to do is to query a database, find some matching users, and, in a query loop, send them to DocuSign to sign a Templated document. So far so good but what I need to be able to figure out is each user gets a unique EnvelopeID so that I can store them in database and later check the status of each EnvelopeID.

In my code, all returned EnvelopeIDs are the same. Maybe that's because they are all within the same session? I do get an status of 201--which means the Envelope is created.

I could share the code here but it will be long code--it's almost the same as the linked document above.

Any idea?

Thanks!

**Update** Oh, I have an idea--my loop is only catching the last returned EnvelopeID... will be back soon

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. In my query loop, during SQL UPDATES, I was simply missing the `WHERE` clause--the API was indeed returning unique EnvelopeIDs when executing within the loop.

Maybe it was the magic of StackOverflow which made me find a solution so quickly!
 ;)